# Can we choose environment(endpoint) from Jenkins to run ReadyAPI tests?

Tags: ready-api

I'm trying to run tests from Jenkins integrated with ReadyAPI and Maven.
currently, i'm switching the environment from a database and running the testcases.

Now, we want to choose the environment from Jenkins, is there any possibility to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the environment to the [command line test runner](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/automation/testrunner/cli) by using the

> -E YourEnvironmentName

parameter.

Comment: Hey, for SoapUI and Jenkins integration, do we require any license for Test server or something? We have SoapUI Pro license

Comment: You can use the command line runner testrunner.bat.  https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/integrations/ci-systems/example.html